# Laravel 5.6 - check if user can create record based on request parameter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

In my app users can create events that are categorised by a related organiser id.

I want to check if the user submitting a request to create a new event has access to the organiser they are creating the event for.

For example:

```
$organiser_id = $request->input('organiser_id');
if($user->hasOrganiser($organiser_id)) {
    // User has permission
}
```

Obviously the above would work in my controller but ideally I would like to achieve this in my EventPolicy class or perhaps in the EventRequest.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel provides many ways to go through this, you can always check the documentation, in the documentation you will find the checks in the controllers(which you can exclude), the model and in the middleware.

check the [authorizing-actions-using-policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization#authorizing-actions-using-policies)

you can always use a [middleware which handles the HTTP requests before hitting your app isntance](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware#defining-middleware) and hence much more control on your app.

> Laravel includes a middleware that can authorize actions before the incoming request even reaches your routes or controllers. By default, the Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize middleware is assigned the can key in your App\Http\Kernel class.

```
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->age <= 200) {
        return redirect('home');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Add it to the [route file](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware#registering-middleware) as the link explains so you can check the request and apply your guard.

```
Route::post('/post', function () {
// The current user may create posts...
})->middleware('can:create,App\Post');
```

you can check the model way as well in the first link.

Comment: Thanks Hamza. I have checked the documentation and have implemented other policies successfully but in this case I need to access the request input from within the policy and I can't see anywhere if this is possible.

Comment: when you say access the request input, you mean you need to check it before it hits your app instance? if that is so, then you need to create a middleware, which handles the http requests before it hits your app instance.

Comment: as per this example you can find the [handle method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware#defining-middleware) in the middleware which reaches to the request before everything else .. for sure you need to register that middleware.

Comment: Ah okay. I could implement this and assign it to the "create event" route?

Comment: yes, that can go there or in your controller, whichever you prefer, but the route method is much easier to track IMHO.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Could you update your answer to be more specific about the middleware solution and I'll mark as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I am traveling atm but I think this will help you.

Laravel uses a class called Auth so you can call that class staticky like: Auth::id()

More info:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help Niels, I'm going to go with @Hamza solution though.

Comment: Ah I see the problem now more clearly. Yes making a middleware is an better solution!